# Highlighting PDFs programatically in .net - are there any APIs or Libraries to generate offset file or is there a better method?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, highlight

I need to programatically highlight PDFs on the fly,  preferrably using the highlight file method.
Are there any .net programming libraries to generate a xml highlight offsets file for a pdf?   Doesnt have to be open source or free.

I tried converting PDFBox to a .net DLL using IKVM and it did not work correctly.   Im not terribly excited about the memory footprint of the entire java class library in the DLL anyway.

a second option would be to regenerate and highlight the source PDF,  if there are any libraries / APIs that will do this to a PDF relatively easily that would work too,  but I have not found any in my searches.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this has solution for your requirement, but this is a good opensource api to work with PDF. I will be so happy if it could help your needs.

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Comment: thanks for the response, but alas,  no,  iTextSharp does not generate the word offset XML file used for highlighting.   

iTextSharp's main focus is creating PDFs.